prove that $a|1$ iff $a=\pm 1$
prove that $a|1$ iff $a=\pm 1$
so this implies
$1=ca$
let's first deal with $\mathbb{N}$
a natural number is always the product of two numbers less than or equal to  it.
so $0 < c \leq 1$
$0 < a \leq 1$
so $0 < ac \leq 1$
but a and c are both natural, thus they must both be equal to $1$
thus $a=1$
not sure of how to prove $a=-1$

If $a$ is anything other than $\pm 1$, isn't $1/a=c$ either undefined or not an integer?

oh right, but can I use that in a proof?

Assuming $a|1$, you'd try for a contradiction and suppose $a\ne\pm1$ and then you'd find out $c$ is not an integer, a contradiction.

Consider $a=0$ which is not a solution and, if not, $|a| \geq 1$. $a | 1$ implies that $|a| \leq 1$. Thus, $|a| = 1$, which is same as $a = \pm 1.$

@RDK Nice direct method. To get the $|a|\le 1$, I suppose we'd say $|a|=1/|c|$ and since $|c|\ge 1$, then $|a|=1/|c| \le 1$.

@J.Chapman Yeap, that seems clearer. Maybe in same method, we can say that $a | b$ implies that $|a| \leq |b|$, as $b=ca$ and $|a|=|b|/|c| \leq |b|$ since $|c| \geq 1$.

Put $,b=1$ in $,b\mid a\mid b\Rightarrow |b|\le |a|\le |b|\Rightarrow |a| = |b|,,$ as in linked dupe.
